# create views for a field submitted more than once in one row

Tags: views

I have a content type that only has one field. (for example weight)
The user submits this field multiple times.
now I want to create a view that shows all the weights submitted by the user in one row, not in separate rows.

How can I create this kind of view?

Answer (score 0):

1)Change your views format into grid set its maximum column

[image]

[image]

[image]

3)Allow Group By Authored into Grids

4)Add css

```
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
```